# PHP's variable type leniency

Tags: php

The most recent comment on PHP's `in_array()` help page (http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php#106319) states that some unusual results occur as a result of PHP's 'leniency on variable types', but gives no explanation as to why these results occur.  In particular, I don't follow why these happen:

```
// Example array

$array = array(
    'egg' => true,
    'cheese' => false,
    'hair' => 765,
    'goblins' => null,
    'ogres' => 'no ogres allowed in this array'
);

// Loose checking (this is the default, i.e. 3rd argument is false), return values are in comments
in_array(763, $array); // true
in_array('hhh', $array); // true
```

Or why the poster thought the following was strange behaviour

```
in_array('egg', $array); // true
in_array(array(), $array); // true
```

(surely 'egg' does occur in the array, and PHP doesn't care whether it's a key or value, and there is an array, and PHP doesn't care if it's empty or not?)

Can anyone give any pointers?

Comment: `in_array` is foremost not intended for comparison against a bag of arbitrarily typed values, but against a list of strings or all integers. Even then it just uses Zends normal weak typing rules. -- Also we shouldn't be discussing php.net manual comments here. Just file a bug report.

Comment: “PHP doesn't care whether it's a key or value” – why do you think `in_array` works on array keys? The documentation summary clearly says “Checks if a **value** exists in an array” (emphasis mine).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally, you can think of the basic in_array() call working like this:

```
function in_array($needle, $haystack, $strict = FALSE) {
    foreach ($haystack as $key => $value) {
        if ($strict === FALSE) {
            if ($value == $needle) {
                return($key);
            }
        } else {
            if ($value === $needle) {
                return($key);
        }
    }
    return(FALSE);
}
```

note that it's using the `==` comparison operator - this one allows typecasting. So if your array contains a simple boolean `TRUE` value, then essentially EVERYTHING your search for with in_array will be found, and almost everything EXCEPT the following in PHP can be typecast as true:

```
'' == TRUE // false
0 == TRUE // false
FALSE == TRUE // false
array() == TRUE // false
'0' == TRUE // false
```

but:

```
'a' == TRUE // true
1 == TRUE // true
'1' == TRUE // true
3.1415926 = TRUE // true
etc...
```

This is why in_array has the optional 3rd parameter to force a strict comparison. It simply makes in_array do a `===` strict comparison, instead of `==`.

Which means that

```
'a' === TRUE // FALSE
```

Answer (score 5):

763 == true because true equals anything not 0, NULL or '', same thing for array because it is a value (not an object).

To circumvent this problem you should pass the third argument as TRUE to be STRICT and thus, is_rray will do a === which is a type equality so then

763 !== true

and neither will array() !== true

Comment: array() != true ;) You probably mean array() == false.

Comment: I shot that out of memory but i've done my certification a long time ago. Thanks for clarifying that. In any case, it works because there is a true and a false in the array, so everything should return true for each in_array call except "maybe" for objects which i'm not sure of.

Answer (score 1):

PHP treating arrays as primitive values is a constant source of pain as they can be very complex data structures, it doesn't make any sense. For example, if you assign array to something, and then modify the array, the original isn't modified, instead it is copied.

```
<?php

$arr = array(
    "key" => NULL
);



var_dump( array() == NULL ); //True :(
var_dump( in_array( array(), $arr ) ); //True, wtf? It's because apparently array() == NULL
var_dump( in_array( new stdClass, $arr ) ); //False, thank god

?>
```

Also, 'egg' is not a value in the array, it's a key, so of course it's surprising that it would return true. This kind of behavior is not ok in any other language I know about, so it will trip over many people who don't know php quirks inside out.

Even a simple rule that an empty string is falsy, is violated in php:

```
if( "0" ) {
echo "hello"; //not executed
}
```

`"0"` is a non-empty string by any conceivable definition, yet it is a falsy value.

Comment: `"0" == false` in javascript and perl as well.

Comment: @MathieuDumoulin, in javascript: `if( "0" ) {alert("hello");}` passes as expected: "0" is a truthy value as it is a non-empty string. In PHP `if( "0" ) {
echo "hello";
}` doesn't do anything even if it's a non-empty string.

Comment: @gnud, it doesn't matter because you don't do that in javascript. You do `if( "0" )` or `if( x === true )`, there is no need to write `if == true` because as you can see it gives unexpected results. The difference is that in javascript `"0"` is a truthy value as is, while in php `"0"` is a falsy value as is. In loose comparison to `true` both get converted to `0` which gives same result in both languages.

Comment: So, javascript treats `if("0")` and `if("0" == true)` differently, and you complain about PHPs weird types?

Comment: @gnud, `if(something)` is well defined in the ecmascript specs and there are no surprises. `NaN, -0, +0, empty string, false, null, undefined` will not pass, while everything else will pass. In PHP, this is not the case as you can see in my reply to MathieDumoulin.

Comment: Well, `if` isn't defined that way in PHP. It's defined to evaluate the boolean value of it's contents, and evaluate the if-block it the boolean value is true.

Comment: @gnud Also, `==` does type coercion depending on operands, while just checking `if(x)` does straight `ToBoolean`. So while `==` is a bad practice in javascript, you at least have a choice if you want to coerce or just see if a value is falsy/truthy as is.

Comment: Worse than the nitpicking above though : Arrays in PHP are copy-on-write. Saying that a simple assignment copies it, is just plain wrong.

Comment: @gnud, right I will fix that. My point was that if you assign an array to something, and then modify it, the original isn't modified.

Comment: Further to all this, if the array is much simpler: `$arr = array("str1","str2")`, the following does return false: `in_array(100, $arr);`, which, as far as I can tell, seems to conflict the `in_array(763, $array);` in my original example. Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: @ChrisW, I guess it's because the original array had a `TRUE` and `763 == TRUE` but `100 != "str1"`